# Xamarin Live Player in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-live-player, visual-studio-2019

I recently  get Visual Studio 2019 preview edition, now I want to use the Xamarin Live Player, but I can't find it anywhere. I know that in previews version of visual studio it was in `Tools / Options / Xamarin / Other` but now it's not.

Comment: I havent seen any official documentation suggesting this, but I get the impression that the LivePlayer isn't a priority for Xamarin at the moment. But there are at least 3 other options out there:

https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload

https://github.com/ylatuya/XAMLator

http://www.livexaml.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some digging on Microsoft Documentations. I find out Microsoft is removing Live Player in VS 2019...!!!